# Maven Dependencies Issues With Spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have downloaded two projects **"chocolatestore-model"** and **"springchocolatestore"** for learning purposes. "springchocolatestore" dependents on "chocolatestore-model" that is, it uses the services in "chocolatestore-model".

In the maven-Dependencies folder of "springchocolatestore", "chocolatestore-model" can be found inside. Now i have created a new project and wants to also use "chocolatestore-model" so that I can use it services. I am finding it difficult how to get it inside the maven-dependencies of my project.

For this reason I decided to copy and paste the same pom.xml of "springchocolatestore" into my new project. After saving the file, "chocolatestore-model" doesn't appear in my new project's Maven-dependencies.

When I first copied the first two projects, the tutorial asked to right-click on "chocolatestore-model" and choose Run-As->maven-install, I don't know if that caused it to install automatically into the "springchocolatestore" maven-dependencies folder or not.

I am a beginner in Maven so it is difficult to understand everything in the POM files. These are the Maven files:

**"springchocolatestore POM.XML":**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.packtpub</groupId>
    <artifactId>springchocolatestore</artifactId>
    <name>springchocolatestore</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring HATEOAS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>0.16.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  Freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Tiles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Chocolate store Model dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.packtpub.springmvc.chocolatestore.model</groupId>
            <artifactId>chocolatestore-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**"chocolatestore-model POM.XML":**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.packtpub.springmvc.chocolatestore.model</groupId>
    <artifactId>chocolatestore-model</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <name>chocolatestore-model</name>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My new project POM.XML is the same as the one of "springchocolatestore" since I also want to use the services of "chocolatestore-model". Only this part changes:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.packtpub</groupId>
<artifactId>springmvc</artifactId>
<name>FirstSpringMVCProject</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

How can I include "chocolatestore-model" in my new project's maven dependencies?

Comment: Dude, It's absolutely easy! Look at: https://maven.apache.org/guides/index.html Really nice documentation! And really good tutorials. Just read it, and will be fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- mvn install does build what we call an artifact (something you can reuse)  and the artifact is available into the maven local repository. After you did an 'install' if you didn't change the Maven configuration, the artifacts (the components you have built) are located into ~/m2/repository (related to the home directory). You can of course check if the 2 artifacts you made are located there in ~/m2/repository/com/packtpub/springchocolatestore and ~/m2/repository/com/packtpub/springmvc/chocolatestore/model/chocolatestore-model. The latest artifact produced is in ~/m2/com/packtpub/springmvc. As you can review you are not very **consistent** in the naming of your artifacts.  You use **springmvc** in the **groupid** and in the **artifactid** **and it is not a good practice.**
- To reuse an artifact, it is very easy. Reference the artifactid into the section dependencies of your pom. 
  You already did it in the pom of *springchocolatestore*:

  `...
      <!-- Chocolate store Model dependency -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.packtpub.springmvc.chocolatestore.model</groupId>
          <artifactId>chocolatestore-model</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>`

  Do the same in the pom of springmvc if you want to use the same dependency.
  If you reuse chocolatestore-model it means where it is used, you can 'well', **use it**. If you want to change the code, you have to rebuild chocolatestore-model. It is NOT at the place where you use it that you can modify it. You change, you rebuild (install) and then use.
- I repeat to check if you can build (locally) the artifact id springmvc, cd to springmvc and then type 
  `clean install`(command line). What is difficult related to Maven in the beginning is than you create a pom.xml with few lines, and then you can build the software locally rather easily (if you follow the conventions of course). It is called conventions over configurations.

Hope it helps a bit.